# How can I migrate my Symfony vhosts from Debian to Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: wordpress, symfony, migration, cpanel

I need help! I want to migrate my vhosts from one server (Debian) with another one (Ubuntu 20.04).
All my virtual hosts has been configured with lamp and symfony.
How can I migrate all?

Thank you in advance for your help!

I've already downloaded cPanel and Symfony module on the new server

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.